# How to save playwright test results as a bitbucket pipeline artifact

Tags: bitbucket, playwright

I'm not sure why I can't get this to work but see below the operative part of the bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
- step:
  script:
    # ...other steps

    # Install Playwright
    - npx playwright install

    # Dummy artifact
    - touch test.txt

    # Run the tests
    - playwright test

  artifacts:
    - "test.txt"
    - "**/test-results"
```

The test.txt file is showing up in the artifacts but the playwright test results don't. the playwright tests fail and produce a test-results folder locally so I'd expect the same to happen in the pipeline? I've tried a few different things but I'm struggling to make progress.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: What exactly have you tried? I would go with `test-results/*`, but have you confirmed it is being created with `ls`?

Answer (score 1):

To anyone coming across this in the future, I was very close. You have to do this:

```
artifacts:
  - "**/test-results/**"
```

Docker messes up the root folder structure...